# Как посмотреть историю платежей в QIWI API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, qiwi

Как посмотреть историю платежей в своём QIWI? Посмотрел пример в документации, но выводит объекты. Как правильно получить историю?

```py
import pyqiwi
wallet = pyqiwi.Wallet(token = "ТОКЕН", number = "НОМЕР")
print(wallet.history(rows=5))
```

Выводит это:

```
{'transactions': [<pyqiwi.types.Transaction object at 0x000000000360BAC8>,
<pyqiwi.types.Transaction object at 0x000000000361F518>,
<pyqiwi.types.Transaction object at 0x000000000361F3C8>,
<pyqiwi.types.Transaction object at 0x000000000361FD68>,
<pyqiwi.types.Transaction object at 0x000000000361FE80>],
'next_txn_id': 25392721556,
'next_txn_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 22, 23, 44, 47, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 10800))}
```

Comment: В чём проблема посмотреть содержимое внутри этих объектов? В документации про них всё есть https://pyqiwi.readthedocs.io/ru/develop/api.html#transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pyqiwi
wallet = pyqiwi.Wallet(token = "ТОКЕН", number = "НОМЕР")
print(wallet.history(rows=2).get("transactions")[0])
```